# The keyboard and trackpad on my MacBook Pro 3,1 stopped working. How to solve this problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, trackpad

The keyboard and trackpad on my macbook pro 3.1 stopped working after having frozen the operating system and reboot.

On my Mac I have Windows installed BootCamp and neither does the keyboard and trackpad.

However, I work a keyboard and mouse connect via USB external. You do not know if it really is a problem hardware or software.

Comment: Does the power button work?

Comment: Yes, the power button work. The only is not working is the keyborad and trackpad of my MacBook Pro. The USB ports is working too.

Comment: What happens when you press the power button and hold the alt/option button?

Comment: Any key on the keyboard is freze. The power button is the only button that work in the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some possible solutions check out:

**Solution 1**

http://gigaom.com/apple/the-curious-case-of-the-missing-macbook-pro-keyboard-and-trackpad/

> If the warranty on your MacBook Pro is no longer valid, like mine,
>   don’t worry. Simply take a small piece of paper, such as a Post-It,
>   and fold it in half. Stick it over the spot on the ribbon cable. Then
>   reinstall the removable battery. The battery should exert enough
>   pressure on the piece of paper to keep the ribbon cable working.
>
> If your MacBook Pro is still under warranty, take it to an Apple
>   service center. While Apple has not officially acknowledged that this
>   is a widespread problem, it’s afflicted the machines of many owners,
>   so surely it’s not unknown to them. Demonstrate the steps described
>   above to whomever is helping you as letting him or her see the problem
>   as it happens eliminates the guesswork and may help expedite the time
>   needed for repairs.

**Solution 2**

http://jasonrobb.com/v2/2008/11/24/macbook-pro-unresponsive-keyboard-trackpad-solution/

> THE FIX? I rolled up a sticky note and placed it on top of the cable.
>   When the battery is locked in place, it puts pressure on the cable,
>   and makes the keyboard and trackpad functional.

**Solution 3 (Apple)**

Apple support forum dedicated solely to this issue:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1365569?start=270&tstart=0

> **THE SOLUTION:**
>
> This is a HARDWARE problem!
>
> After playing around with removing the battery and noticing that this
>   often returned functionality to the keyboard I surmised that this had
>   some sort of physical aspect. Sure enough, there is a section of
>   copper colored tape/wiring exposed in the batter slot that is slightly
>   bowed where it's smallest. When I depressed this with my finger tip on
>   this portion to basically flatten it out flush against the housing; I
>   found that all functionality was restored!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! Please o not just post links to offsite resources without providing some context and / or giving a summary: linked resources can go away anytime, thus making your answer useless, and it is rude to force the readers to read the whole threads and / or sites to judge on their merit.